Why did Oppenheimer say "Wormhole" in this scene?
In the chemistry lab,Patrick Blackett and Niels Bohr are standing across a table from each other, while Bohr is advising Oppenheimer:

Bohr: Get to Germany, study under Max Born. Learn the ways of theory. I'll send word.

Then Bohr brought the apple to his mouth to eat, but Oppenheimer snatched it and tossed it into the trash can:

Oppenheimer: Wormhole.
Bohr: How's your mathematics?

Why did Oppenheimer say "Wormhole" in this scene?

It's also clearly meant as a subtle nod to the astrophysical concept, though the term wasn't in use until 1957 when it was coined by John Wheeler. Note that this scene is mostly a fabrication. The incident is at least claimed to be real, but Bohr was not involved and Oppenheimer did not manage to get away with it by pretending the apple was wormy. (Source: Vanity Fair)

I had to turn on captions to even understand the line. It took me a minute to understand that Oppenheimer meant the apple had been eaten into by a worm, rather than admit he had put cyanide in it with a syringe. In real life it seems that Oppenheimer did try to put some chemical in Blackett's apple, but that incident probably happened when Bohr wasn't in town.

Oppenheimer had poisoned the apple in an attempt to harm Prof. Blackett.
When he sees Bohr about to eat it he disposes of it by saying he saw a worm hole in the apple so Bohr wouldn't want to eat it.
Wormed apples are quite common.


Q: What's worse than finding a worm in your apple?
A: Consuming cyanide
